# how to display the xml content page wise in a mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile app in which i am getting the data's from a xml file. But the problem that i am facing here is that i am getting all the xml contents together but in the mobile app i want to show it page wise, That is the first page will have 5 products, the second will have next 5 products and so till the end of products. so how can i do it.

here is the html and javascript file which i use to read, parse and display

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dvContent").append("<div></div>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/donotdel/d/cat.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('product').each(function(){
            var sModel = $(this).find('model').text();
            var sName = $(this).find('name').text();
            var sDescription = $(this).find('description').text();
            var sImage = $(this).find('image').text();
            var sPrice = $(this).find('price').text();
            var sSpecial = $(this).find('specialPrice').text();
            $("<li></li>").html(sModel + ", " + sName + ", " + sDescription + ", " + sImage + ", " + sPrice + ", " + sSpecial ).appendTo("#dvContent div");
        });
        },
        error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
     });
   });    
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 body
 {
   font-family  : Arial;
   font-size  : 10pt;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div id="dvContent">

</div>
</form>
```

now in this i am getting all the products but i want to get only 5 products each time and display and on clicking next or the page number i want them to go to that page where i show the other 5 products. so how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it sounds like you know how to parse the XML into data, but you only want to show 5 at a time. What I would do is this:

Parse the XML.
Write a generic function that shows rows X to Y.
Call that with 1-5.

In your page include two buttons. Add touchend listeners to them such that when you click one (nextButton or somesuch), it simply runs the generic function to show the next 'page' of data.

You'll need to remember the total # of items so you don't go beyond the end, and obviously don't let folks go below 1.